# Winforms ReportViewer passing null for parameters even when the parameters are set

Tags: winforms, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2

Even though I set the parameters in the code, I keep getting that a parameter must be set error.  I have run profiler to see what is being passed to SSRS, and profiler indicates that parameters = null.  Yet all of them are set in code.  Anyone have any ideas?  The code is as follows:

```
string strReportPath;
      Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter prmFranchiseOID;
      Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter prmSchoolOID;
      Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter prmRoomOID;
      Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter prmOrderDate;
      Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter prmLanguage;
      Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter prmContrast;
      List<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter> prms = new List<ReportParameter>();
        byte[] pdf = null;

        try
        {
            prmFranchiseOID = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("FranchiseOID", "8D126AA2-2E5C-4B2B-8D19-167027F8C7D8");
            prmSchoolOID = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("SchoolOID", "96FEE335-0CB9-413A-9DDC-78F8C67770C4");
            prmRoomOID = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("RoomOID", "null");
            prmOrderDate = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("OrderDate", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date.ToString());
            prmLanguage = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Language", "en-CA");
            prmContrast = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Contrast", "true");

            prms.Add(prmFranchiseOID);
            prms.Add(prmSchoolOID);
            prms.Add(prmRoomOID);
            prms.Add(prmOrderDate);
            prms.Add(prmLanguage);
            prms.Add(prmContrast);

            // Note: For Account Holder users, their specified report folder is "/LunchLady/User".
            strReportPath = "/LunchLady/Franchise/" + urlReportName;

            try
            {
                rvReport.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri("https://testsql.thelunchlady.ca/ReportServer");
                rvReport.ServerReport.ReportPath = strReportPath;
                rvReport.ServerReport.SetParameters(prms);

                string ReportType = "PDF";

                pdf = rvReport.ServerReport.Render(ReportType);
```

Thanks

Comment: Which parameter is causing this issue?  Or it is all of them?

Comment: @user2840110 Your code seems to be incomplete. Could you please post the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Having done extensive programming on the SSRS controls in ASP.NET, one thing that I've found which may or may not be relevant for WinForms is that each SSRS parameter is actually a collection in itself (due to parameters being able to be multi-select).

So what worked for us is that the collection (prms in your case) was of type

```
List<IEnumerable<ReportViewer.ReportParameter>> prms
```

Also when adding parameters using the SetParameters function we added them one at a time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < prms.Count; i++)
{
    rvReport.ServerReport.SetParameters(prms[i]);
}
```

Again, this is what worked for us in ASP.NET, could be something for you to try.